# How do you properly construct an Accelerate array using fromPtr in Haskell?

Tags: opencv, haskell, type-families, type-signature, accelerate-haskell

I'm trying to use `fromPtr` from accelerate-io to scoop an image out of OpenCV and into an Accelerate array. The documentation for this feature is obtuse, and [this example](https://github.com/AccelerateHS/accelerate-examples/blob/master/examples/canny/beholder/Process.hs) won't compile (I can't install accelerate-examples because of Criterion). This code:

```
import Foreign.Ptr
import Foreign.C.Types

import AI.CV.CxCore
import AI.CV.HighGui

import Data.Array.Accelerate as A
import Data.Array.Accelerate.IO as A
import Data.Word

main :: IO ()
main = do
  capture <- cvCreateCameraCapture 0
  frame <- cvQueryFrame capture
  imgPtr <- cvGetImage frame -- Ptr IplImage -> Ptr Word
  arr <- A.fromPtr (Z :. 480 :. 640) ((), castPtr imgPtr)
  return ()
```

results in `Couldn't match expected type 'BlockPtrs (EltRepr e0)' with actual type '((), Ptr b0)'. The type variables 'e0', 'b0' are ambiguous.`

Removing the `castPtr` gives me `Couldn't match expected type 'BlockPtrs (EltRepr e0)'              with actual type '((), Ptr Word8)'. The type variable 'e0' is ambiguous.`

Looking at the definitions for `BlockPtrs` and `EltRepr` only makes me more confused. But, adding a type signature to the expression, as in `(((), imgPtr) :: BlockPtrs ((), Word8))` gives an expected type of `BlockPtrs (EltRepr e0)` and an actual type of `BlockPtrs ((), Word8)`.

Does anyone here have experience with `fromPtr`?

**EDIT:** Getting closer. I tried to use the constructor EltRepr before, but it didn't occur to me to import its originating module. D'oh! But, now that I have done so, replacing the type signature with `:: BlockPtrs (EltRepr Word8)`:

```
Couldn't match type `BlockPtrs (EltRepr e0)' with `((), Ptr Word8)'
The type variable `e0' is ambiguous
Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
Expected type: BlockPtrs (EltRepr e0)
  Actual type: BlockPtrs (EltRepr Word8)
```

**EDIT:** Answered by Reid Barton. It compiles for me now, thanks! "Final" code:

```
import AI.CV.CxCore
import AI.CV.HighGui

import Data.Array.Accelerate as A
import Data.Array.Accelerate.IO as A
import Data.Array.Accelerate.Array.Sugar (EltRepr)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  capture <- cvCreateCameraCapture 0
  frame <- cvQueryFrame capture
  imgPtr <- cvGetImage frame
  (arr :: Array (Z :. Int :. Int :. Int) Word8) <- A.fromPtr
      (Z :. 480 :. 640 :. 3)
      (((), imgPtr) :: BlockPtrs (EltRepr Word8))
  return ()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fromPtr :: (Shape sh, Elt e) => sh -> BlockPtrs (EltRepr e) -> IO (Array sh e)
```

GHC needs to know which type `e` you want to use `fromPtr` at to provide the `Elt e` instance.

Apparently `EltRepr` is a type family/associated type, so `EltRepr e` does not determine `e`. (There's no reason why there can't be two types `e1` and `e2` for which `EltRepr e1` and `EltRepr e2` are the same type.) So GHC can never conclude from the types of the arguments to `fromPtr` which type `e` to use.

`Array` is an ordinary type constructor, so `Array sh e` does determine `e`. So you should put a type ascription on `arr` instead.

```
  (arr :: Array (Z :. Int :. Int) Word8) <- A.fromPtr (Z :. 480 :. 640) ((), castPtr imgPtr)
```

(This will require some extension which GHC will let you know about.) Or, if you actually use `arr` in a way that determines the type of its elements to be `Word8`, you won't need this type ascription.